# I can't get the $set operator to work on a specific field

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, backend

I am writing a database backend for our game. I have been wrestling for the past 3 days with this issue. No matter what I try, I cannot get the `$set` operator to work on one field. Just one.

I have a `GlobalLeaderboard` collection, with each document containing this structure:

```
{
    "_id" : { "$oid" : "5e7d445f5010bb548850d2ee" },
    "PlayerName" : "Regen_erate",
    "Rating" : 38.24,
    "TotalMapsPlayed" : 372,
    "UserId" : "P526993347"
}
```

The Node.js code that I am running to edit the database is as follows:

```
rating = await getRating(Plays.find({"UserId": newPlayData.UserId}).sort({"Rating": -1}));
console.log(rating);
Global.findOneAndUpdate({"UserId": newPlayData.UserId}, 
            {
                $inc: {"TotalMapsPlayed": 1},
                $set: {"PlayerName": newPlayData.PlayerName},
                $set: {"Rating": rating.toFixed(2)},
                $set: {"UserId": newPlayData.UserId}
            },
            {
                upsert: true,
                bypassDocumentValidation: true,
                ignoreUndefined: true
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log("ERR: " + err);
                res.status(500).send("Whoops! Something went horribly wrong! Here's some info: " + err);
            });
```

Even if I stick a random number (double) into the `$set` operation it still won't update. This seems to be happening for no reason at all...

I am able to run `$set` on all other fields except the `Rating` field. Out of curiosity, I tried to use `$inc` on the field in question, and, surprisingly, I was able to get it to work. What is going on?

Comment: where are your trying & please post code which is failing & if doing it directly on DB post your query as well..!!

Comment: This update works fine: `db.getCollection('GlobalLeaderboard').update({},{$set:{Rating:44.48}})`

Comment: I'm not trying to update the whole collection, just one document.

Comment: @whoami I was able to get it to update with the $max operator?????????

Comment: @blizzo : what are you doing here :: `rating = await getRating(Plays.find({"UserId": newPlayData.UserId}).sort({"Rating": -1}));
` ?? If `UserId` is unique in your collection you would get only one doc out then why to use `.sort()` ? Also did you try to print what `rating` is getting printed as - Your mongoose schema could be blocking new `rating` value to be updated in DB?

Comment: @whoami its printing as 41.07, calculated from my plays. Plays is a different collection, that is queried by the UserId and is sorted because the rating calculation algorithm bases rating on your top 25 scores.

Comment: @blizzo : So you mean to say `Plays.find({"UserId": newPlayData.UserId})` will result in an array of plays for a user !! Ok then that case after `.sort()` try to use `.lean()` like this `.sort({"Rating": -1}).lean()`. I hope that should be the issue, if even this doesn't work, try to add `mongoose.set("debug", true);` in your code & print actual query going from code to DB to see what query is being executed !!!

Comment: I'm not using mongoose btw, im using regular mongodb driver

Comment: @whoami         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: @blizzo : then not sure where the issue is check .toFixed(2) is working fine or not as you need to usually parse and then do ‘toFixed’ try to print that..

Comment: @whoami unfortunately I have tried to put some random number in and it still wont update...

Comment: @whoami it seems to be just one field... do you think a field got corrupted??

Comment: @blizzo not sure what the issue is, I’ve only seen once a doc has an issue updating which is uploaded via mongocompass we deleted it and created again then everything has gone to normal. Try that or check your code line to line and try to remove extra options and give it a try

Comment: @whoami it seems that feilds that were created as a double value have trouble being `$set`... hmm

Comment: i guess its time to go to SQL?

Comment: @blizzo : I was so confused when you said all other fields are updating but I would say they might not be, try this `.findOneAndUpdate({"UserId": "P526993347"},{
                $inc: {"TotalMapsPlayed": 1},
                $set: {"PlayerName": 'Regen_erate2',"Rating": 41.07, "UserId": "P526993348" }
            },{upsert : true})` Issue is you cannot do multiple `$set`'s. So for now instead of multiple `$set`'s put all fields in an object & do set on that object everything will work. In multiple set's only last set will be executed.

Comment: @blizzo : if your MongoDB version >=`4.2` you can use aggregation pipeline to use multiple `$set`'s, that will something look like `[{$set}, {$set}]` an array.. Also from your query you don't need this :: `$set: {"UserId": newPlayData.UserId}`, try & let me know..

Comment: Holy crap I'll try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second argument to `findOneAndUpdate` is an object.  An object can only have 1 instance of a specific field name, when you specify the same field multiple times, the last one is the value that remains.  So your update document:

```
           {
                $inc: {"TotalMapsPlayed": 1},
                $set: {"PlayerName": newPlayData.PlayerName},
                $set: {"Rating": rating.toFixed(2)},
                $set: {"UserId": newPlayData.UserId}
            }
```

Is equivalent to

```
           {
                $inc: {"TotalMapsPlayed": 1},
                $set: {"UserId": newPlayData.UserId}
            }
```

To set multiple fields in the same update, list all of the fields inside a single `$set` like:

```
           {
                $inc: {"TotalMapsPlayed": 1},
                $set: {"PlayerName": newPlayData.PlayerName,
                       "Rating": rating.toFixed(2),
                       "UserId": newPlayData.UserId}
            }
```

Comment: THANK YOU THAT FIXED IT :DDDDDD